# JavaScript Prototype Problem: I don't understand this error

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiaOz.png)

Line 7 has a problem I can't debug the problem it suggest I have to use ==> ; 
but when I put ==> ; another problem being found in my code.
I'm completely confused..

Comment: [Pictures of code are not very helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) we can't run the code, can can't copy and paste the code, some people can't even read the code. Provide a [mcve] in text instead, preferably in the form of a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Please post code, no images.

Answer (score 0):

The method definition for your `Question.prototype` needs to look something like this:

```
Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function() { // lines of code
};
```

And, of course, please take note of the comments to your post above. Posting some lines of code instead of an image makes it so much easier for everyone here to help you.

Answer (score -1):

missing keyword function after displayQuestions

Answer (score -1):

Adding a function to an Object is a done with `= function() {` not `() {`

```
Question.prototype.displayQuestions = function() {
  // your code here
};
```

I suggest you look at the Person samples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Answer (score -1):

Write

```
Question.prototype.displayQuestions = function() { ... }
```

or

```
Question.prototype.displayQuestions = () => { ... }
```

Comment: What's wrong with my answer to justify the downvote? How should I improve it?